# Issue outputting flush to SSE

Tags: php, unix, server-sent-events

I can't figure this one out.

I am currently running my SSE (Server Sent Event) back-end code in it's own file.

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of 
event data.

function sse_send($msg) {
  echo "id: " . time() . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: " . $msg . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

I am calling this file via shell_exec() passing 1 variable which I want to send to the client.

My issue is, I can see the string is being passed as $argv[1] but I can't send it to the client as it returns 0. I can manually type it's value into the send function and it will work. I can compare $argv[1] === 'insert its value here' and it will yield true but for some reason it won't send to the client if I use $argv[1] or any other variable I have assigned it's value to.

Comment: `$argv` and `$arv` do not appear at code at Question

Comment: you've created a function ... sse_send ... you never call the function ... also, this is not related to javascript at all

Comment: SSE == Server SENT Events

Comment: @guest271314: Fixed typos - Meant $argv[1].

Comment: @JaromandaX I apologized, I thought it was implied that I was calling the function, also the information is received on the client through javascript.

Comment: `$argv` still does not appear at code at Question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `include()` of your external file, not `shell_exec()`. It will be more efficient, more reliable (no chance to get caught up in safe mode restrictions) and most importantly, it should then work.

I've assumed the php script calling `shell_exec()` is running in the web server. When you call a php script with `shell_exec()` it runs it as a separate php process, with its own stdin/stdout/etc. You need to be running `flush()` in the process running inside your web server, and the same for `ob_flush()`.

Comment: Thanks for your input Darren! My issue was with miss understanding how to set up things properly on my end. 

I was able to get it to work by passing a get variable to my SSE.php file that would identify the loading bar I was trying to update - I would then record the progress in the DB and all my SSE.php had to do was report that progress back to the client. The record would then be removed once it reached completion. 

Achieving a loading bar for my script was harder that it should of been! Tried to do it through sessions but learned about session locking the hard way!